# Use implicit differentiation to determine partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

Use implicit differentiation to determine $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ in $yz=ln(x+z)$ and $ \sin(xyz)=x+2y+3z$.

Here is my answer:

$$ yz=ln(x+z) $$
$$ yz'=(1+z')\frac{1}{x+z} $$
$$ z' = \frac{1}{yx+yz-1} $$

and

$$ \sin(xyz)=x+2y+3z $$
$$ y(z+xz')\cos(xyz)=1+3z' $$
$$ yz\cos(xyz)+xyz'\cos(xyz) = 1+3z' $$
$$ yz\cos(xyz) - 1 = z'(3-xy\cos(xyz)) $$
$$ z' = \frac{yz\cos(xyz) - 1}{3-xy\cos(xyz)} $$

is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Don't forget the chain rule, and to include other instances of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

For instance, in the first, don't forget that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(yz) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}z + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$

and in the second, don't forget that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} ( x + 2y + 3z) = 1 + 2\frac{\partial y} {\partial x} + 3\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$

Otherwise, your techniques look reasonably ok.

Comment: why? isn't y regarded to be a constant in this partial derivative?

Comment: In that case, why would $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$ but $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \neq 0$?

Comment: As in, yes, normally both $y$ and $z$ would be regarded as constants in the partial derivatives and therefore have no derivatives. But since you are asking for the implicit derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$, $z$ must vary with $x$. We cannot assume that $y$ does not also vary with $x$ (unless this is explicitly stated).